# how to implement thread process in phonegap development?

Tags: cordova

I am developing phonegap application that reads json data from server but it stops the execution of current process untill the javascript got executed.

i want to execute the process like thread.

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript in the WebView does not run on the UI thread. It runs on the WebCore thread. The execute method also runs on the WebCore thread.

If you need to interact with the UI, you should use the following:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you do not need to run on the UI thread, but do not want to block the WebCore thread:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In the PhoneGap Android code I inferred  that PhoneGap has 
an embedded Server and the javascript calls made from UI to native are 
through that embedded server and hence the callbacks can executed in a 
Separate Thread.